# cognos 10.2.2 -Report Studio

Tags: report, cognos-10

I have attached the report output.If you see the report output , the  column ‘Total_Hotel_Charge’ highlighted in yellow is showing the amount in UK pound. But I don’t understand why . when I checked  in the property of the column and   found the Data format is set to ‘Currency ‘  but not set to UK pound . please see the screen shot .

So my questions is  why it’s taking UK pound as default ? Is there something could be set in ID studios?Anyone else faced this kind of issue ?If yes could you suggest me some thing to resolve this ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur6lt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1wqi.png)

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your response .Could you let me know where this default currency would be set?  Some where in cognos configuration file ?I have already seen that changing the property does changes the currency  format in report  .But curious to know where the default currency has been set .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Data Format dialog, the Format type is set to Currency and no Currency is chosen.  This makes it use the default currency, which I assume is UK pound.  You can correct that by choosing a specific value in the Currency property.  Don't trust the sample being displayed at the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: Thank you for your response .Could you let me know where this default currency would be set?  Some where in cognos configuration file ?I have already seen that changing the property does changes the currency  format in report  .But curious to know where the default currency has been set .

Comment: A simple search produced:  https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21335849
If you add a data item with this macro `#sq($runLocale)#` you'll see it.  On my system, I'm pretty sure this comes from Active Directory.

Comment: you are right . for me it shows en-gb . Thank you for your help